# Caliburn Action not firing

Tags: caliburn.micro

```
<ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Right"  x:Name="Actions">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="Action"  
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Content="{Binding Label}" 
                    Margin="3" Width="30"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>

        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The above view binds with this viewmodel

```
public class DeploymentInputViewModel<T> : PropertyChangedBase
{
   public BindableCollection<InputActionViewModel> Actions {get;set;}
}
```

I see my buttons. But when clicking it nothing happen.

The viewModels for InputActionViewModel:

```
public abstract class InputActionViewModel{
    public InputActionViewModel()
    {

    }
    public virtual Task Action()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    public string ActionToolTip { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

and also

```
public class InputCertificateActionViewModel : InputActionViewModel
{
    [Import]
    private IShell _shell;
    [Import]
    private IWindowsDialogs _dialogs;

    private readonly IDeploymentSettingInputViewModel vm;
    public InputCertificateActionViewModel(IDeploymentSettingInputViewModel vm) 
    {
        this.vm = vm;
        Label = "...";
        ActionToolTip = "Pick a Certificate";
    }

    public bool IsManagementCertificate {get;set;}
    public bool IsDeploymentCertificate { get; set; }
    public async override Task Action()
    {
        if(IsManagementCertificate)
        {
            var subs = await _shell.IdentityModel.GetEnabledSubscriptionsAsync();
           foreach(var sub in subs)
           {
               using (ManagementClient client = CloudContext.Clients.CreateManagementClient(sub.GetCredentials()))
               {
                   var cert = _dialogs.SelectItemDialog("Select a certificate", "Pick one", true,
                       (await client.ManagementCertificates.ListAsync()).Select(c =>
                           new SelectItem(c.Thumbprint, Encoding.Default.GetString(c.PublicKey), c, (s) => c.Thumbprint.Contains(s))).ToArray())
                           .Tag as ManagementCertificateListResponse.SubscriptionCertificate;
                   this.vm.Value = cert.Thumbprint;
               }

           }


        }else if(IsDeploymentCertificate)
        {

        }



    }
}
```

I am adding actionViewModels by inserting directly into the observable code at startup.

```
haveActions.Actions.Add(DI.BuildUp(new InputCertificateActionViewModel(vm)
{
    IsDeploymentCertificate = certAttribute.IsDeploymentCertificate,
    IsManagementCertificate = certAttribute.IsManagementCertificate,
}));
```

haveActions is an instance of InputCertificateActionViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't fit this all in a comment:

I can't have a peek at the `Caliburn.Micro` at the moment, but it might be something related to calling your method `Action`.

At a guess though, I'd say that by convention `Caliburn.Micro` expects to find a method that matches the `Action<T>` delegate to use for it's `Actions`, so your `public virtual Task Action()` won't be located and bound.

Have a quick check by defining a new method with a compatible signature, e.g `public void MyMethod()` and checking to see if it's located correctly and will function.

If that is the problem, you'll probably want to have a look at the `IResult and Coroutines` part of the [`Caliburn.Micro` documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation), which looks like it will help you implement your desired behaviour.

Comment: Ye Method called Action was a bad idea :)

Comment: Aha, good to know =D So it's quite happy to fire a method `public virtual Task NewName()`? Learned something new =D

Comment: Ye, I changed things abit also added a attach message and thats how I noticed Action Didnt work as I changed it to something like MyAction then it said it could find method My if I recall correctly.